# Right mysql table design/relations in this scenario

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, relational-database, entity-attribute-value

I have this situation where i need suggestions on database tables design.

**BACKGROUND**

I am developing an application in PHP ( cakephp to be precise ). where we upload an xml file, it parses the file and save data in databases. These XML could be files or url feeds and these are purchased from various suppliers for data. It is intended to collect various **venues data from source urls , venues can be anything like hotels , cinemas , schools , restaurants** etc.

**Problem**

Initial table structure for these venues is as below . table is deigned to store generic information initially.

```
id
Address
Postcode
Lat
Long
SourceURL
Source
Type
Phone
Email
Website
```

With the more data coming from different sources , I realized that there are many attributes for different types of venues.

For example 
a hotel can have some attributes like

```
price_for_one_day, types_of_accommodation, Number_of_rooms etc
```

where as schools will not have them but have different set of attributes.Restaurant will have some other attributes.

My first idea is to create two tables called vanue_attribute_names ,  Venue_attributes

```
##table venue_attribute_names
_____________________________
id
name

##table venue_attributes
________________________
id
venue_id
venue_attribute_name_id
value
```

So if I detect any new attribute I want to create one and the its value in attributes table with a relation. But I doubt this is not the correct approach. I believe there could be any other approach for this?. Besides if table grows huge there could be performance issues because of increase in joins and also sql queries

Is creating widest possible table with all possible attributes as columns is right approach? Please let me know. If there any links where I could refer I can follow it . Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is a surprisingly common problem.

The design you describe is commonly known as "Entity/Attribute/Value" or EAV. It has the benefit of allowing you to store all kinds of data without knowing in advance what the schema for that data is. It has the drawback of being hard to query - imagine finding all hotels in a given location, where the daily roomrate is between $100 and $150, whose name starts with "Waldorf". Writing queries against all the attributes and applying boolean logic quickly becomes harder than you'd want it to be. You also can't easily apply database-level consistency checks like "hotel_name must not be null", or "daily_room_rate must be a number".

If neither of those concerns worry you, maybe your design works.

The second option is to store the "common" fields in a traditional relational structure, but to store the variant data in some kind of document - MySQL [supports XML](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/xml-functions.html), for instance. That allows you to define an XML schema, and query using XPath etc.

This approach gives you better data integrity than EAV, because you can apply schema constraints. It does mean that you have to create a schema for each type of data you're dealing with. That might be okay for you - I'm guessing that the business doesn't add dozens of new venue types every week.

Performance with XML querying can be tricky, and general tooling and the development approach will make it harder to build than "just SQL".

The final option if you want to stick with a relational database is to simply bite the bullet and use "pure" SQL. You can create a "master" table with the common attributes, and a "restaurant" table with the restaurant-specific attributes, a "hotel" table with the hotel attributes. This works as long as you have a manageable number of venue types, and they don't crop up unpredictably.

Finally, you could look at NoSQL options.

Comment: thank you. While I know that I can save data in xml files or some files , but I never used that way, I always have a belief that storing data in files against a database is wrong idea. I now I see that I am wrong in some cases. I will try options you say and see if I can get what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sticking with a relational data base, that's it. The options you listed are pretty much what they can give you.

For your situation [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/) (or an other document oriented NoSql system) could be a good option. This db systems are very good if your have a lot of records with different atributes.

Comment: unfortunately choosing another database is not an option now. There has been a lot of development happened and we are almost done except that design. what I explained is just part of application and there is lot more.

Comment: There's no need to put everything into MongoDb. Just save what you get in XML into MongoDb and make it accesible with a service(-class) for the rest of your application.